# how to inactivate segue in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, prepared-statement, segue

Hi guys i made an app and what i want to do is
when you click "select" button in navigation bar item, i want to make it to click multiple items and the code for that is just to enable `collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = true` which works.

[click to view an app image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYdm1.jpg)

but at the same time i want to make if the user didn't click the select button but the item, i want to show next view controller.

so now, whenever i clicked the image, it directly shows the next view controller since i connected them in storyboard. i want to inactivate it when the "select" button is clicked.

how? do i have to use the prepare func? and not use the storyboard? please tell me the simplest way to do it

thanks

Answer (score 0):

One simple way of solving this:

1. Connect the entire view controller that contains the images with the other view controller through a segue.
2. Add an identifier to this segue, which you will use later.
3. Create a function that segues to that view controller when an image is pressed. - *Up to here is just another way of implementing the code that you have implemented*
4. Create a boolean variable, which is set to false when the select button is on ( and the opposite )
5. Add an if check to your function in number 3. that only segues when the boolean variable is true.

This ensures that if the select button is pressed, you don't segue when images are clicked.